# Why can't I create a React native project using the expo init command?

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, expo

I have installed Expo for this to configure the proxy and the installation was successful.

```
npm install -g expo-cli
```

Then I executed the following command line:

```
expo init AwesomeProject
```

But I get the following error:

> ```
> C:\Users\sault>expo init awesomeProject
> ? Choose a template: expo-template-blank
> request to https://registry.npmjs.org/expo-template-blank failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.16.18.35:443
> Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.
> ```

What could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried many solutions eventually only this works for me, just to intercept the request and modify the `options` before sending request.

#### File Name

```
/Users/[your user name]/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/minipass-fetch/lib/index.js
```

#### Code

```
// pick an npm registry host as you like
if (options.host === 'registry.npmjs.org') {
  options.host = 'registry.npm.taobao.org';
  options.hostname = 'registry.npm.taobao.org';
  options.href.replace('registry.npmjs.org', 'registry.npm.taobao.org');
}
```